# How do I install unix build tools on OSX 10.6?

Tags: macos, unix

I'm trying to get a full unix build environment on my Mac I have installed XCode.

The main reason for this is to get Mono building and it requires configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XCode installer already has the unix toolchain. You can get it by checking "UNIX Development" on the "Installation Type" step.

As for Mono, you can get it (framework and/or monodevelop) directly from the official site as an OS X installer: http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably something like [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).  This is a collection of ported linux packages and a package management system.  After you install the base system, you can say something like

```
sudo port install autoconf
```

This will install `autoconf`, plus anything that it depends on.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have installed the Xcode tools, I would suggest that you install Mono using the [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) package manager. Use this command after you install MacPorts:

```
sudo port install mono
```

You can build it yourself as well after that but this way you have all the dependencies installed for you. At the very least, it would help to see how [MacPorts builds Mono](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/devel/mono/Portfile) if you would still like to do it yourself.